# group properties - sorting not in an alphabetical order

Tags: sorting, grouping, reporting-services

In a group I have four items that SSRS sorts alphabetically:
Assigned,
New,
Old,
Renew,

I wish the report would be in this order :
New,
Renew,
Assigned,
Old,

How can I accomplish this in "group properties" > "sorting"  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up you Group Sorting property with an expression similar to the following:

```
=Switch(Fields!yourField.Value = "New", 1
  , Fields!yourField.Value = "Renew", 2
  , Fields!yourField.Value = "Assigned", 3
  , Fields!yourField.Value = "Old", 4)
```

Basically you're creating a calculated value based on your field and ordering by this calculated value.

Obviously you'll need to update your field details with the correct name.

**Edit after comment:**

I've put together a small example to confirm this is working as expected. First, create a sample Dataset:

[image]

I've created a sample report with a Table based on the Dataset:

[image]

The grouping is based on *Status*. By default, this is set up to be sorted by the same field at the group level, i.e. alphabetically bu *Status*.

[image]

The results reflect this:

[image]

Next step is to apply the expression based sorting at the group level. I used the exact same expression as above, substituting `Status` for `yourField`. The result is now sorted as required:

[image]

So you can see that the suggested solution does work. Next question - why doesn't it work for you? If you're absolutely sure you've implemented this correctly at the group level, I can only think that there is sorting being applied in a child group.

For examples, when created, a table will have a **Details** group by default to show individual rows in the Dataset - it's possible that sorting is set up here and it's preventing the parent level sort from working correctly. I would check all groups in the table and the table sorting expression too and remove any unexpected sorting that has been set up.

Comment: Didnt work.  It moved them around but not as expected.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have added details showing this in action and working as required. In you case, I would check any child groups like `Details` so see if sorting is set up there and affecting the parent group sorting. Other than that, standard troubleshooting - create a new table with the absolute minimum detail, get the sorting going, then keep adding required functionality checking that sorting is still working at each step.